# Generate random percentage using oracle sql

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the below table account_ownership:

```
account    holder
A1         H1
A1         H2
A2         H3
A2         H4
A2         H5
A3         H6
A3         H7
A3         H8
A3         H9
```

Below is what i need.

Output:

```
account    holder   ownership
A1         H1       50
A1         H2       50
A2         H3       50
A2         H4       25
A2         H5       25
A3         H6       60
A3         H7       30
A3         H8       5
A3         H9       5
```

Note: The ownership can have any value between 1 and 99 (no fractional part) but it should add up to 100 within the account.

Comment: [This](https://www.databasejournal.com/features/oracle/article.php/3341051/Generating-random-numbers-and-strings-in-Oracle.htm) might be useful to you

Comment: Random part is easy. The trick part is to enforce the sum is always 100.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
WITH tbl1 (acct, hldr)
         AS (SELECT 'A1', 'H1' FROM DUAL
             UNION ALL
             SELECT 'A1', 'H2' FROM DUAL
             UNION ALL
             SELECT 'A2', 'H3' FROM DUAL
             UNION ALL
             SELECT 'A2', 'H4' FROM DUAL
             UNION ALL
             SELECT 'A2', 'H5' FROM DUAL
           )
select acct, hldr,
       case when rn=1 then 100-sum(percent) over(partition by acct)+percent
       else percent end AS percent
  from (
select acct, hldr,
       ceil(dbms_random.value(1,100/count(1) over(partition by acct))) percent,
       row_number() over(partition by acct order by NULL) rn
  from tbl1
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this. The logic is explained inlined.

```
--Dataset

WITH tbl1 (acct, hldr)
     AS (SELECT 'A1', 'H1' FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 'A1', 'H2' FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 'A2', 'H3' FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 'A2', 'H4' FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 'A2', 'H5' FROM DUAL),
     --dataset end
     -- Counting records for each account
     tbl2 (acct, cnt)
     AS (  SELECT acct, COUNT (1)
             FROM tbl1
         GROUP BY acct),
     -- Counting end
     tbl3 (acct,
           hldr,
           prcnt,
           rnk)
     AS (SELECT tbl1.acct,
                tbl1.hldr,
                ROUND (100 / tbl2.cnt) prcnt,
                DENSE_RANK ()
                OVER (PARTITION BY tbl1.acct ORDER BY tbl1.acct, tbl1.hldr)
                   rnk
           FROM tbl1 INNER JOIN tbl2 ON tbl1.acct = tbl2.acct)
SELECT tbl3.acct,
       tbl3.hldr,
       CASE
          WHEN (rnk = 1) AND MOD (tbl2.cnt, 2) = 1 
           THEN (prcnt + 1)
          ELSE prcnt
       END
  FROM tbl3 
 INNER JOIN tbl2 
 ON tbl3.acct = tbl2.acct
 ORDER BY ACCT;
```

Comment: Thanks!! Works great for even number of holders but not for odd number of holders.

Comment: @L30n1d45 As mentioned inline, for odd number of holders, the result would have decimal part as per my logic. So incase you need the exact sum = 100, remove  `Round` and then run.

Comment: i don't want any fractional part.

Comment: @L30n1d45 See the revised answer.

Comment: fails for 5,7 and other odd number of holders.

Answer (score 1):

Use SQL as below.

```
WITH account_ownership (account, holder)
             AS (SELECT 'A1', 'H1' FROM DUAL
                 UNION ALL
                 SELECT 'A1', 'H2' FROM DUAL
                 UNION ALL
                 SELECT 'A2', 'H3' FROM DUAL
                 UNION ALL
                 SELECT 'A2', 'H4' FROM DUAL
                 UNION ALL
                 SELECT 'A2', 'H5' FROM DUAL
                 UNION ALL
                 SELECT 'A3', 'H6' FROM DUAL),
        table1 as(
        select a.account,holder,
               sum(1)over(partition by a.account order by holder) as myorder,
               b.mycount,
               dbms_random.value(1,100) myvalue
        from account_ownership a
        left join (select account,count(*) mycount
                   from account_ownership
                   group by account) b
        on a.account = b.account),
        table2 as(
        select a.account,holder,myorder,mycount,trunc(myvalue/sumvalue*100) true_value
        from table1 a
        left join ( select account,sum(myvalue) sumvalue                        from table1
                    group by account) b
        on a.account = b.account)
        select account,holder,case when myorder != mycount then true_value
                                   else 100 - sum_value + true_value end as ownership
        from (select account,holder,myorder,mycount,true_value,
                     sum(true_value) over (partition by account order by myorder) as sum_value
              from table2)
```